# Dropwizard runming static page with JavaScript sources

Tags: javascript, java, dropwizard

I want to run a html file on dropwizard.

these are there scripts that I want to run:

```
<script src='http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='x.js'></script>
    <script src='y.js'></script>
```

So in my initialize method:

I have this:

```
  bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "index.html"));
   bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/",  "x.js"));
 bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "y.js"));
  bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "style.css"));
```

I get a 404 error, when I run dropwizard. However I have tried running a simple html file with no javascript and that was able to run fine. Can you use java script sources outside of dropwizard?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success referring to static assets in Dropwizard. My *initialize* method simply created the default AssetsBundle:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle());
```

which means that static assets are expected in `src/main/resources/assets`and should be referenced for URL purposes using `/assets/<file name>`

My HTML references were like this:

```
<script src="/assets/abc.js"></script>
```

Invoking *AssetsBundle* with parameters, as you have done, should be fine, but you should only need a single *addBundle* invocation. (Keep the first one, lose the rest. The last parameter is the default index file name, and doesn't come into play in your case since you have explicit file names in your paths.) In the HTML template, try modifying your paths so that they are absolute, eg:

```
<script src="/x.js"></script>
```